# facebook api js (angular) check if two people friends returning empty array

Tags: javascript, facebook, angularjs, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I have a small angularJs app that needs to check if two people are friends on facebook..

As I following the facebook official api guide: [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/friends#readmodifiers)

from the guide:

```
    /* make the API call */
FB.api(
    "/{user-id-a}/friends/{user-id-b}",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);
```

my code:
(isFriends watching the place in the array to get updated by facebookIsFriends)

```
$scope.isFriends = function(friend_id){
    //$scope.myArray[friend_id]
    var tmpStr = 'myArray.' + friend_id;
    $scope.facebookIsFriends(friend_id);
    var unbindWatcher = $scope.$watch(
        tmpStr,
        function() {
            if(!!$scope.myArray[friend_id]){
                unbindWatcher();
               //call another function with the result.
            }
        }
    );
}

$scope.facebookIsFriends = function(friend_id){
  var urlString = '/' + $scope.user.id + "/friends/" + friend_id;
  Facebook.api(urlString, function(response) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
      $scope.myArray[friend_id] = response;
    });
  });
 }
```

i get in return:

```
data: Array[0]
    length: 0
__proto__: Array[0]
summary: Object
    total_count: 754
__proto__: Object
```

**note**: I do have 754 friends.

**important notes**: 
    1.when i try to try this [in the graph api explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) I get similar result! (I absolutely sure I checked all of the use data & extended permissions.
    2.I'm connected properly to facebook, i did already some queries that worked properly (/me, /me/feed,/{post-id})
    3.When I debug the code, I get a proper url string, like:
    **/10204551896346735/friends/10205037578119229** 
    when I try to put each of these user-is's in the graph-api-explorer i get good results(non-empty user objects)

I already tried million things, like set a long timeout and check if it's updated over time but nothing happens. please help I lost all hope :(

thanks,
Matan

Comment: Have you tried calling the Facebook API with hard-coded data and no AngularJS? Just running  Facebook.api(urlString, function(response) { console.log(response); });

Comment: I did try it.. after i changed the api explorer to the Graph Explorer application it did work so I guess the problem is in the app itself.. any ideas?